EF Core check for substring ignore whitespace and case
Say I have following EF core class:
public string Rhyme
{
    public int Id {get;set;} 
    public int Text {get;set;} 
}

Imagine I have record in DB with text "The quick brown Fox jumps over the lazy dog" where spaces are non-breaking. I want to find this string it by string "brown fox" where space is ordinal.
What is the most efficient way to do that using EF Core?

What is most efficient way to do that in SQL? Answering on this can be solution for your question.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv, I'd like to do it using just EF Core. But if there is no working solution, I'd like to have SQL code.

Well, I mean that you have started from the wrong side, you have to find way how to do that in the SQL - one question, second question how to execute it via EF Core. Also what do you mean spaces non-breaking and what is ordinal spaces?

Ignoring the questionable parts:

where spaces are non-breaking
where space is ordinal
public int Text { get; set; }

And assuming the following (corrected the Text type to string and added some seed data for the example):
public class Rhyme : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Rhyme>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; } = null!;

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Rhyme> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.Text)
            .HasColumnType("text");

        builder
            .HasData([
                new Rhyme { Id = 1, Text = "The quick brown Fox jumps over the lazy dog" },
                new Rhyme { Id = 2, Text = "The quick Brown Fox jumps over the lazy dog" },
                new Rhyme { Id = 3, Text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" },
                new Rhyme { Id = 4, Text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" },
                new Rhyme { Id = 5, Text = "foo bar" },
                new Rhyme { Id = 6, Text = "brown fox" },
                new Rhyme { Id = 7, Text = "bob and alice" },
            ]);
    }
}

You can filter the entities using the Where method with the following predicates and results:



Predicate
Result (matched strings)
Note




r => r.Text == "brown fox"
"brown fox"
Literal string equality.


r => EF.Functions.Like(r.Text, "%brown fox%")
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "brown fox"
Matched by the pattern (case sensitive), LIKE statement


r => EF.Functions.ILike(r.Text, "%brown fox%")
"The quick brown Fox jumps over the lazy dog", "The quick Brown Fox jumps over the lazy dog", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "brown fox"
Matched by the pattern (case insensitive), ILIKE statement


r => r.Text.Contains("brown fox")
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "brown fox"
Same as EF.Functions.Like statement



Example:
// example query
var result = await dbContext.Ryhmes
  .Where(r => r.Text.Contains("brown fox"))
  .ToListAsync()

See Npgsql docs (since you have tagged the question with postgresql).
